# Is there a way to access Wikipedia tree for disambiguation pages and categories?

Tags: wikipedia, wikipedia-api, word-sense-disambiguation

1) for example try visiting : [http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Architecture_(disambiguation)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Architecture_%28disambiguation%29)

-->Is there any wikipedia api via which I can access this?

2) for example try visiting : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Architecture
When you do right at the bottom of the page, there is a Categories: Architecture Architectural design Greek loanwords

-->Is there a way to get this data? Preferably in form of a tree?

Comment: The category structure of Wikipedia isn't a tree. While it should be a multitree or at least a DAG, in the enWP it isn't even that - its just a directed graph

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [MediaWiki Query API](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API%3aQuery); although it doesnt return trees or something similiar complex. You'd have to structure it yourself.

For example, you could get the list of all pages in the Category:Disambiguation pages and get all the links on each page in that list.

Comment: I wanted to use similarity measures like Lin, Resnik, etc. Hence if it wa a tree it would really help

Comment: Of what do you want to measure similiarity? I'm sorry, I've never heard of those algorithms. Could you explain them or link a good ressource?

Comment: they are WordNet Similarity measures to check how related 2 terms are so that I can choose the appropriate sense in the context